# How can I prevent scrollbar from appearing on top of modal background

Tags: html, css, background, modal-dialog, css-position

I'm placing a fixed position modal inside a relatively positioned element with no transforms and with overflow: auto.

The problem is that when there is overflow on the parent, the modal's backdrop does not cover the scrollbars - please look at the picture attached for an example.

[image]

The scrollbar should also be covered by the semi-transparent black backdrop, but for some reason it is not. Does anyone know why, and/or how I may go about fixing this?

I want to avoid using absolute positioning for the modal container because it can be a nested element in any arbitrary hierarchy.

Here is my css for the .modal-container class which includes the backdrop.

```
.modal-container {
position: fixed;
top: 0;
left: 0;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.5);
opacity: 1;
transition: all .1s;
display: flex;
z-index: 200;
justify-content: center;
align-items: center;}
```

Comment: I have since fixed this error. It was because I had a fixed position container inside a transfromed element, which gave it a new perspective. I had to either render my element in a sibling element to its parent or remove the transform style from the parent to fix.